# Use method to Return value int in C#

Tags: c#, string, methods, int, return

I'm taking a programming class in c# and it is our first week and I'm trying to work ahead a little. To that end, I am trying to rework one of our class labs and am stuck with my 'GetInt' method.

Ideally, the GetInt method (line 50) takes in a string (Enter a number) and returns the number as an int so i can then use it to do some math. Currently line #24 turns the test error 'Cannot implicity convert type 'int' to 'string'.

Any help is appreciated. I am very much a newb, so please don't assume i know anything.
Thank you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace lec022_If_statement_int
{
class Program
{
    //Set to public so it is visible
    //void because it returns nothing
    //Play is a method within the class Program I've added
    public void Play()
    {
        DisplayStr("Lecture 2c | If Statements with ints");
        DisplayReturns();

        DisplayStr("Welcome to Dunut King");
        DisplayReturns();

        //Collect User Name
        //GetString converts to lower, trims
        String numDonuts = GetInt("How many donuts would you like?: ");
        DisplayReturns();

        //Display welcome
        Console.WriteLine("You asked for " + numDonuts + " donuts.");
        DisplayReturns();

        DisplayReturns();
        DisplayStr("Have a great Day!");
    }



    //MaxBox 2.0
    public void DisplayStr(String StrTxt)
    { Console.Write(StrTxt); }

    public void DisplayReturns()
    { Console.Write("\n\n"); }

    public string GetString(String StrVar)//note - using strings here
    {
        Console.Write(StrVar);
        return Console.ReadLine().ToLower().Trim();
    }

    public int GetInt(string intVar)//note - using ints here
    {
        Console.Write(intVar);
        return int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    //Initiate Program
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program myProgram = new Program();
        myProgram.Play();

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Of course right after I post my question i figured out the answer. I need to state that line 24 is an 'INT' not a 'String' because I am asking for an INT to be returned, not a String. I hope that that is correct. I have my code working now by changing the word 'string' to 'int' on line #24.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `GetInt` method returns `int`. So you need to change from

`String numDonuts = GetInt("How many donuts would you like?: ");`

to

`int numDonuts = GetInt("How many donuts would you like?: ");`

Comment: Thank you - Soon as i posted it i realized what I had done. I guess i just needed to see it somewhere else to get the boot to the head i needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the method `GetInt` returns `int`.

And you're trying to assign its return value to this String variable on line 24.

```
String numDonuts
```

You cannot do this.

Answer (score 1):

Change the first word on line #24 from 'String' to 'int' because I am asking for an int not a string.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is there:

```
    String numDonuts = GetInt("How many donuts would you like?: ");
```

You try to set int value to string variable.

change to

```
var numDonuts = GetInt("How many donuts would you like?: ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your GetInt method returns integer type so you should use an integer type to store it, not a string.

Here is the fixed code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;



namespace lec022_If_statement_int
{
class Program
{
    //Set to public so it is visible
    //void because it returns nothing
    //Play is a method within the class Program I've added
    public void Play()
    {
        DisplayStr("Lecture 2c | If Statements with ints");
        DisplayReturns();

        DisplayStr("Welcome to Dunut King");
        DisplayReturns();

        //Collect User Name
        //GetString converts to lower, trims
        int numDonuts = GetInt("How many donuts would you like?: ");
        DisplayReturns();

        //Display welcome
        Console.WriteLine("You asked for " + numDonuts + " donuts.");
        DisplayReturns();

        DisplayReturns();
        DisplayStr("Have a great Day!");
    }



    //MaxBox 2.0
    public void DisplayStr(String StrTxt)
    { Console.Write(StrTxt); }

    public void DisplayReturns()
    { Console.Write("\n\n"); }

    public string GetString(String StrVar)//note - using strings here
    {
        Console.Write(StrVar);
        return Console.ReadLine().ToLower().Trim();
    }

    public int GetInt(string intVar)//note - using ints here
    {
        Console.Write(intVar);
        return int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    //Initiate Program
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program myProgram = new Program();
        myProgram.Play();

        Console.Read();
    }
}
}
```

I've just tested the program. You enter a number and you get a response. Works nicely. (For it's simple purpose :-) )

Comment: Thank you for the help, i figured it out right after i posted the question. Still, thank you for the help - that is awesome of you to help others like that and I for one appreciate it. Cheers!